# How to convert multiple rows(but one column) into a single row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a single row from multiple rows (has only one column). Please help me how to do this. The number of rows is variable.

```
select column_name from information_schema
where table_name='temp'
```

Here `temp` has 5 columns and the output will be:

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
```

But I want the output as:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

Comment: Give an example and show the expected result please.

Comment: Look for the "group by" clause and aggregate functions in Google.

Comment: @xdazz, havee added the sample IP & OP.